# Using Watir and Selenium how to add certificate to profile for Firefox?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, firefox, watir

I'm trying to run Firefox via the Watir gem with a predefined profile that has a certificate for authorization. I created a new profile for Firefox and manually added the certificate. Now I can't run Watir browser with this profile.

I tried to set profile path.

```
profile_path = '/path/to/profile'
profile=Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name(profile_path)
browser_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: browser_options
```

I also tried set profile via Waitr options

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: {args: ['-profile', '/path/to/profil']}
```

Maybe it is a possibility to add certificate during initialize Watir::Browser

UDAPTE::

When I type in firefox `about:profiles` I see that firefox use my predefinied profile, but isn't true.

Comment: Can you clarify, *"Now I can't run Watir browser with this profile."*? What do you mean by can't run? Do you receive an error? Please update the question with the expectation and the current outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
profile_path = '/path/to/profile'
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new(profile_path)
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: { profile: profile }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got error 
`No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /tmp/webdriver-rb-profilecopy20240320-139-5g84ck/lock (Errno::ENOENT)`

For sure my profile_path is corret. I can `cd` to this folder.

Comment: Either you have to use the single quote and single slash like this `'C:\Users\rajagopalan.m'` or you have to use the double quote and double backslash like  `"C:\\Users\\rajagopalan.m"`